# Shopping Cart PLUS & MINUS Calculate the total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a shopping cart and i need to get the value of Item increse ( + and - )
and add it to the item price.

### Shopping Cart +/- Control

[image]

### In my view Code goes like this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="cart-qty nostretch text-center">
                <div class="spinner" data-addclass-on-smdown="spinner-sm">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle" id="btnMinus"><i data-feather="minus"></i>-</button>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="999" id="numberCol">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle" d="btnPlus"><i data-feather="plus"></i>+</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="cart-price text-right">
                <span class="roboto-condensed bold" id="primaryTotal">Rs:@item.ItemPrice</span>
            </td>
}
```

and also i have tried to get the No.Of item in On change function .. but it's not success.I need when someone increse or decrese item then need to calculate the price accoding to it.

### My JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnMinus, #btnPlus").click(function (e) {
        alert($("#numberCol").val());
        $("#primaryTotal").val('@item.ItemPrice'+);
        debugger;
    });
});
```

Comment: The view code you posted seems to be incorrect. You have a closing bracket, but no open bracket. Also you cannot have a `td` tag without a table row and table. Post the correct relevant piece of code. Also I am still not able to 100% understand your expected behavior.

Comment: also, you are not changing anything in `$("#numberCol")`, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value somewhere for the price, so I set up a `data-price` and added a pair of spans to make it easier to format.  You had a typo on the id for one element so I fixed that.  I also added a table/tbody to make it easier to test my sample.  IF you have a lot of these in a table, you will need to NOT use id's and use classes relative to the clicks instead.  I also addressed issues with "count" where entry could be made to `1.67` for instance and rounded it to an integer.

I added super simple validation that `Math.round()` way.  Note how I put the price in using the view model - but set a default for this example, remove that prior to use.

Do NOT rely on this for actual values, it is super easy to hack for free stuff, so do that server side.

```js
function calculateValues(e) {
  console.log("recalc");
  let item = $('#numberCol');
  let itemCount = Math.round(item.val());
  item.val(itemCount);
  let total = $("#primaryTotal");
  let price = total.find(".price");
  let priceValue = price.data("price") * 1;
  let totalValue = priceValue * itemCount;
  price.text(totalValue.toFixed(2));
 // console.log("recalc val", priceValue, itemCount, totalValue);

}
$(function() {
  //setup a fake value remove for real code
  $("#primaryTotal").find(".price").data("price", 123.45);
  $("#btnMinus").add("#btnPlus").on('click', function(e) {
    //console.log('plus minus', this.id);
    let num = $('#numberCol');
    let numValue = Math.round(num.val()) * 1;
    if (numValue < num.attr("min")) {
      numValue = num.attr("min") * 1;
      num.val(Math.round(numValue));
    }
    if (numValue > num.attr("max")) {
      numValue = num.attr("max") * 1;
      num.val(Math.round(numValue));
    }
    if (this.id === "btnMinus") {
      numValue--;
    } else {
      numValue++;
    }
    num.val(numValue).trigger('change');
   // console.log('plus minus val', numValue);
    //calculateValues(e);
  });
  $("#numberCol").on('change', calculateValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <td class="cart-qty nostretch text-center">
      <div class="spinner" data-addclass-on-smdown="spinner-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle" id="btnMinus"><i data-feather="minus"></i>-</button>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="999" id="numberCol" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle" id="btnPlus"><i data-feather="plus"></i>+</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cart-price text-right">
      <span class="roboto-condensed bold" id="primaryTotal"><span>Rs:</span><span class="price" data-price="@item.ItemPrice">@item.ItemPrice</span>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```